# jRuby called in Ant can't find gems, what am I doing wrong

Tags: ruby, ant, rubygems, jruby, gems-in-a-jar

I have the following in an Ant target:

```
<java jar="tools/jars/jruby-complete.jar" fork="true">
    <arg value="-r"/>
    <arg value="tools/jars/chunky_png.jar"/>
    <arg value="-r"/>
    <arg value="tools/jars/compass.jar"/>
    <arg value="-S"/>
    <arg value="compass/compass-compile.rb"/>
    <arg value="${basedir}"/>
</java>
```

Assume the paths are correct (I've changed them slightly for this example).

My build is failing because the Gems can't be found with an error message:

```
`report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem chunky_png (~> 0.12.0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

If I install the Gems via `gem` this will work, but I don't want to do that because I can't guarantee what will be on the build server.

Comment: Initial hunch is it's something to do with specifying more than one `-r` param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem ended up being that I had created my `chunky_png.jar` incorrectly.

Having a look at [Gems in a Jar](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar) I noticed that my `.jar` should contain a `specifications` directory, which my `.jar` didn't.

Fixing up how I created the `.jar` resolved the issue.

Comment: I also decided to use a `<script>` block instead of `<java>` calling jRuby, but the core problem was with an incorrectly packaged `.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

The [command line parameter documentation](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyCommandLineParameters) for JRuby doesn't have spaces between the `-r` flag and the library. Does the following work?

```
<java jar="tools/jars/jruby-complete.jar" fork="true">
    <arg value="-rtools/jars/chunky_png.jar"/>
    <arg value="-rtools/jars/compass.jar"/>
    <arg value="-S"/>
    <arg value="compass/compass-compile.rb"/>
    <arg value="${basedir}"/>
</java>
```

Another thing to try would be putting the archives containing your gems on the classpath for your `java` task.

Comment: The `-r` argument is also used by standard Ruby. I'm wondering if you should just be specifying the library name e.g. `chunky_png` and `compass` and I suppose again making sure the gem archives are on the classpath.